# I am getting a "Unable to Load Content Error" when I am trying to use the "AWS Transfer to SFTP" service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I selected "`aws transfer for sftp`" service from aws console. 
However, I get the error as follows:

```
Unable to load content
Something went wrong, you may not have permissions to access these resources. Refresh to try again.
```

I created the `IAM Policies and Role` as mentioned in the following guide, however I still get the error:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/sftp.ug.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are administering your account with an IAM user rather than root (which is good). If so, you are going to need to create your own IAM Policy for the creation and maintenance of the AWS Transfer servers.

**WARNING: THIS IS FOR SERVER MANAGEMENT, NOT FOR THE SFTP USERS**

## Steps

- Sign into AWS Console
- Navigate to IAM Roles
- In the left menu, click "Policies"
- Click Create Policy
- Service: choose Transfer
- Actions: check "All Transfer Actions" (transfer:*)
- Resources: All resources
- Click Review Policy
- Give it a name like: `AWSTransferFullAccess`
- Click Create policy
- Navigate to your IAM user (or group if you have those)
- Click Add Permissions
- Click Attach existing policies directly
- Filter your policies by "Transfer" and then yours should appear
- Review
- Add Permissions
- Log out of console
- Log back in and navigate to: https://console.aws.amazon.com/transfer

You should now be able to make a server and manage users and roles.

Answer (score 1):

You might need various `transfer:*` permissions in one of the IAM policies that applies to you.